# Scopus search for a DOI and retrieve authors

Tags: python, scopus

I'm trying to get the authors of a publication by using scopus. For that I got an API key and startet. I searched for the DOI and got a response. Everything is fine, there is also an entry "authors", but for each request this field is simply empty. My code in python is below:

```
import pyscopus
key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
doi = '10.1016/0270-0255(87)90003-0'
scopus = pyscopus.Scopus(key)
response_json = json.loads(scopus.search(f'doi({doi})', view='STANDARD').to_json(orient="records"))
```

So a s I sayed, you can call `response_json['authors']` but it is always empty. There are authors given on the website, but webscraping is forbidden. Am I doing something wrong or do they simply not provide these information (which is confusing, since there is a field)? So far I couldn't find an answer.

I know there are other ways like crossref to get these information, but for reasons I want to do it with scopus.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question and used your code to try to get similar thing. It turns out that the default 'STANDARD' view does not include author. However, you can get authorids via the 'COMPLETE' view.